# ssl handshake error

Tags: apache, ssl

Can you help me
to understand the origin of this error ....  11 bytes expected !?!
tnx
ag

[Fri Dec 23 10:37:39 2011] [debug] ssl_engine_kernel.c(1769): OpenSSL: Handshake: start
[Fri Dec 23 10:37:39 2011] [debug] ssl_engine_kernel.c(1777): OpenSSL: Loop: before/accept initialization
[Fri Dec 23 10:37:39 2011] [debug] ssl_engine_io.c(1523): OpenSSL: I/O error, 11 bytes expected to read on BIO#19ed40 [mem: 1bf268]
[Fri Dec 23 10:37:39 2011] [debug] ssl_engine_kernel.c(1806): OpenSSL: Exit: error in SSLv2/v3 read client hello A